# Novel of a human girl living in a wolf pack and works in the garden

Tags: story-identification, novel, werewolf

The story line starts with the human girl talking to her mother and she’s expressing how she can not wait to leave the pack of wolves relives on. She works in the garden and loves it especially since the grounds are magical and the harvest grows quickly. It’s almost her sanctuary. As she finishes planting the seedling she knows that scent is the new alpha but he hates her. He pushes her away saying how she will dirty him, she tell him to leans and he reminds her that he will become alpha the next day and that those are his lands she works on and that any work done on his land is to benefit him. He also reminds her he knows she will turn 21 the day after he’s appointed alpha.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: Please [edit] for clarity: "leave the pack of wolves relives on", "she tell him to leans". What's the importance of "he knows she will turn 21". Also, when, roughly, did you read this? Where (book, magazine, online)?